# How to delete the text between the insertion point and the start of the line or paragraph

Tags: shortcut

Just like `Control-K` delete the text between the current cursor position and the end of the line, I would like to delete the text between the start of the line and the current cursor position with a hotkey. My current flow is `Command-Shift-Left Arrow` in order to select the text and then `Delete`. I read [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236), but there is no such hotkey. What are my options?

Comment: Command-Shift-Arrow (left or right) has always worked like that for me. I wonder if you use a different keyboard. Mine is the English US and has always selected the text between the cursor and the beginning (or end) of the line. Perhaps if you include your macOS version and what keyboard is in use, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually use Ctrl+W to delete a word to the left, or Option+Del to delete a word to the left. The most consistently available as you mentioned is Cmd+Shift+Arrow then Delete. If you wanted Unix/Bash (readline) shortcuts to make it easy to look up again, Ctrl+U was used for "delete left of cursor". I used it frequently on ChromeOS to delete my password if my muscle memory told me I'd gotten it wrong, but then they removed that option at some point.

[https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash#:~:text=command%20is%20unbound.-,Killing%20and%20Yanking,-kill%2Dline%20](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash#:%7E:text=command%20is%20unbound.-,Killing%20and%20Yanking,-kill%2Dline%20)

> Killing and Yanking
>
> kill-line (C-k) Kill the text from point to the end of the line.
>
> backward-kill-line (C-x Rubout) Kill backward to the beginning of the line.
>
> unix-line-discard (C-u) Kill backward from point to the beginning of the line. The killed text is saved on the kill-ring.
>
> kill-whole-line Kill all characters on the current line, no matter
> where point is.
>
> kill-word (M-d) Kill from point to the end of the
> current word, or if between words, to the end of the next word. Word
> boundaries are the same as those used by forward-word.
>
> backward-kill-word (M-Rubout) Kill the word behind point. Word
> boundaries are the same as those used by backward-word.
>
> shell-kill-word (M-d) Kill from point to the end of the current word,
> or if between words, to the end of the next word. Word boundaries are
> the same as those used by shell-forward-word.
>
> shell-backward-kill-word
> (M-Rubout) Kill the word behind point. Word boundaries are the same as
> those used by shell-backward-word.
>
> unix-word-rubout (C-w) Kill the
> word behind point, using white space as a word boundary. The killed
> text is saved on the kill-ring.

You will likely need to create a custom shortcut with Automator or Karabiner Elements that combines the Cmd+Shift+Left Arrow with Del when you press Ctrl+U or whatever combination is available that makes sense to you.

Comment: For me, control+u deletes the entire line even if the cursor is in the middle of it.

Answer (score 0):

- To **delete everything** *backward* from cursor **to the start** of the line:

  > <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>
- To **delete everything** *forward* from cursor **to the end** of the line:

  > <kbd>⌃ control</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>
- To **delete one word** *backward* from the cursor:

  > <kbd>⌃ control</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>
- To **delete one word** *forward* from the cursor:

  > <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>
- To **delete the entire line** *regardless* of the cursor position:

  > <kbd>⌃ control</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>

---

*Checked on macOS Ventura 13.3.1 in both native Terminal and [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com).*